# Why do I have to manually capture the COM Context (COM Threading with `IRDPSRAPITransportStreamEvents`)

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, remote-desktop

When calling methods on `IRDPSRAPITransportStreamEvents` from .Net Framework, I get `E_FAIL` being returned by `QueryInterface`.  I'm not sure why .Net is doing a QI during a method call since the interface is already the desired one - but I'm ignoring that.  The only way I can get the call to succeed is to invoke through `IContextCallback` captured from a particular thread.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'RDPCOMAPILib.RDPTransportStreamEventsClass' to interface type 'RDPCOMAPILib.IRDPSRAPITransportStreamEvents'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{EA81C254-F5AF-4E40-982E-3E63BB595276}' failed due to the following error: Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).'

For example, this fails:

1. Call comes in from RDP worker thread (Thread 3 - MTA, according to `Thread.CurrentThread`) to method on `IRDPSRAPITransportStream`
2. Call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to do background work, call to `IRDPSRAPITransportStream` returns
3. Background work calls `IRDPSRAPITransportStreamEvents` (Thread 5 - MTA), throws `E_FAIL`

But this succeeds:

1. Call comes in from RDP worker thread (Thread 3 - MTA, according to `Thread.CurrentThread`) to method on `IRDPSRAPITransportStream`
2. Call `CoGetObjectContext(typeof(IContextCallback))` to capture COM Context
3. Call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to do background work, call to `IRDPSRAPITransportStream` returns
4. Background work occurs, then invokes via the captured `IContextCallback` to `IRDPSRAPITransportStreamEvents` (Thread 6 - MTA)

Both calls (the failure and the success) are from an MTA thread.

Why is it required to manually capture the COM context? Shouldn't the marshaller be putting the call on the right thread?  How does one MTA thread succeed, but another fail?

Full repro is on Github ([failing version](https://github.com/mgaffigan/RemoteAssistanceSample/blob/MTAFails/RdpDsViewer/Form1.cs), [succeding version](https://github.com/mgaffigan/RemoteAssistanceSample/blob/master/RdpDsViewer/Form1.cs)).

Comment: It just isn't thread-safe, not remarkable for a COM library.  Nice that it tells you instead of silently exposing you to a threading race bug.  Keep the workaround.

Comment: In the code you use, you do have a mix of STA and MTA threads. Both `RdsDsTransportStream` instances are created on STA (UI thead). But the `Open` method is called on MTA for "sharer" and on STA for "viewer". So the `events` variable is on the MTA for "sharer" `events` and on the "viewer" STA for viewer `events`. Now you want to use these `events` variables in another thread of yours which is always MTA. This is were things fail, when the "viewer" `events` variable (STA) is accessed from your thread's (MTA),etc. The calling context wrapper ensures the object is always called the way it should.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Interesting!  I didn't notice that Viewer was calling from STA.  The other direction [does seem to allow](https://github.com/mgaffigan/RemoteAssistanceSample/blob/ViewerSTAFails/RdpDsViewer/Form1.cs) calls from any old thread.  So then the question becomes a more understandable "Why is .Net/COM runtime not marshalling to a background STA thread?"  Since this is all in process, would RDP failing to marshal the `IRDPSRAPITransportStream` or `events` pointer explain this behavior?

Comment: You pass a COM reference/pointer from a thread (the implicit RDP one used in `Open`) to another (your thRead_Main). This is bad :-) COM can only do its marshaling work when you go through COM methods (like `Open`), otherwise you must marshal it yourself (CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream  blahblah) or use IContextCallbackas as in your working code.

Comment: @SimonMourier, `CoMarshalInterThread*` [(Github)](https://github.com/mgaffigan/RemoteAssistanceSample/blob/CoMarshalInterThreadFails/RdpDsViewer/Form1.cs) and `RoGetAgileReference` [(Github)](https://github.com/mgaffigan/RemoteAssistanceSample/blob/AgileReferenceFails/RdpDsViewer/Form1.cs) fail with the same `E_FAIL` on unmarshalling events to the MTA thread.  Seems only to succeed with `IContextCallback`.

Comment: Also, I thought that .Net RCW's would do automatic marshalling?  I can't find anything explicit that says so, but [`runtimecallablewrapper.cpp` et al.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/coreclr/vm/comcache.cpp#L574) has a lot of references to marshalling for the right context.  To complex to follow without becoming a time vampire, though...